# Can series (A, B) be cointegrated if (A, B, C, D, E, F) are cointegrated?

Tags: time-series, cointegration, spurious-correlation

If the result of series A and B shows cointegration, is this a spurious regression if series A,B,C,D,E,F were found cointegration as well?

My explanation is that , if the stochastic trend series A can be explained by the stochastic trend of series B with residual being white noise, it can't be at the same time when stochastic trend series A can be explained by the stochastic trend of series B,C,D,E,F with residual being white noise. Any comments on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider the following counterexample. Let $x_t$ be a random walk and $\varepsilon_{A,t}$ through $\varepsilon_{F,t}$ be i.i.d. noise sequences. Let $A_t:=x_t+\varepsilon_{A,t}$, $B_t:=x_t+\varepsilon_{B,t}$, ..., and $F_t=x_t+\varepsilon_{F,t}$.
Clearly, $A_t$ and $B_t$ are cointegrated because $A_t-B_t=\varepsilon_{A,t}-\varepsilon_{B,t}$ is a linear combination of two stationary sequences, which is also stationary.
At the same time, any subset of $\{A_t,\dots,F_t\}$, including the full set, is cointegrated because it is always possible to find a linear combination that cancels out the random walks and we are left with a weighted sum of stationary processes, which is itself a stationary process.